# Appcache broken pipe

Tags: android, cordova, application-cache

If I open my appcache phonegap app in offline mode, it loads the page but suddenly it starts to flash with a blank page and in the logcat I can see a huge number of this snippet:

D/CordovaWebViewClient(  873): onPageStarted(https://myserver.com/android/index.html)
D/CordovaActivity(  873): onMessage(onPageStarted,https://myserver.com/android/index.html)
W/SocketClient(  110): write error (Broken pipe)
D/CordovaWebViewClient(  873): onPageFinished(https://myserver.com/android/index.html)

What's happening?